# Provide parameters to Stanford CoreNLP OpenIE from command line

Tags: stanford-nlp

I run OpenIE from Stanford CoreNLP through command line with

```
java -mx1g -cp stanford-corenlp-<version>.jar:stanford-corenlp-<version>-models.jar:CoreNLP-to-HTML.xsl:slf4j-api.jar:slf4j-simple.jar edu.stanford.nlp.naturalli.OpenIE -openie.resolve_coref
```

But when I want to get output for all annotators I am using

```
./corenlp.sh -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,natlog,mention,openie,coref
```

How can I provide parameter `-openie.resolve_coref` to OpenIE and get not only it's output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to simply pass the property `-openie.resolve_coref` using the regular pipeline. I suspect your mistake here is that you have the `coref` annotator after `openie`, and so there's no coref information yet when the OpenIE annotator is run.

Comment: When I run `./corenlp.sh -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,natlog,mention,openie -openie.resolve_coref` OpenIE do not resolving coreferences. And I need both OpenIE output and Coref output.

Comment: Yes, add coref to the end of the annotators list.

Comment: Err... add 'coref' to the end of the list, but before `openie`. So it should be: `./corenlp.sh -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,natlog,mention,coref,openie -openie.resolve_coref`

Comment: As of the most recent version, you need to [remove mention from the annotators list](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/issues/789) or [replace it with coref.mention](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/annotators.html). `./corenlp.sh -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,natlog,coref,coref.mention,openie -openie.resolve_coref`